# Filter duplicated rows based on selected columns and comparing with another dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given two dataframes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creating a DataFrame object   
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('Stuti', 28, 'Varanasi'), 
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi'), 
            ('Aaditya', 25, 'Mumbai'), 
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi')],  
                   columns = ['Name', 'Score', 'City']) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame([('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi'), 
            ('Saumya', 32, 'Mumbai'), 
            ('Aaditya', 40, 'Mumbai'), 
            ('Seema', 32, 'Delhi')],  
                   columns = ['Name', 'Score', 'City'])
```

How could I create a mask for `df2` to filter duplicated rows based on `df1` and columns `Name` and `City`, if same paire existed in `df1`, then return `check` column with `Duplicated`, otherwise, return `None`.

The expected result will like:

```
    Name  Score      City       Check
0   Saumya     32     Delhi  Duplicated
1   Saumya     32    Mumbai        None
2  Aaditya     40  Dehradun  Duplicated
3    Seema     32     Delhi        None
```

Updated code:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df[df.duplicated(['Name', 'City'])]
```

Out:

```
      Name  Score    City
3   Saumya     32   Delhi
0   Saumya     32   Delhi
2  Aaditya     40  Mumbai
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare both columns converted to `Multiindex` form compare by pairs:

```
m = df2.set_index(['Name','City']).index.isin(df1.set_index(['Name','City']).index)
df2['Check'] = np.where(m, 'Duplicated', None)
print (df2)
      Name  Score    City       Check
0   Saumya     32   Delhi  Duplicated
1   Saumya     32  Mumbai        None
2  Aaditya     40  Mumbai  Duplicated
3    Seema     32   Delhi        None
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
In [65]: df2.merge(df1[['Name', 'City']].drop_duplicates(), how='left', indicator='Check').assign(Check=lambda x: np.where(x['Check'] == 'both', 'Duplicated', None))
Out[65]:
      Name  Score    City       Check
0   Saumya     32   Delhi  Duplicated
1   Saumya     32  Mumbai        None
2  Aaditya     40  Mumbai  Duplicated
3    Seema     32   Delhi        None
```